# Cut me and weep? Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I am confused. Someone asked me to tell the name, but I find it difficult.

He told that it is used in our daily life.

Hint

> If you cut me, I will make you weep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [image] 
>  It's onion because if we try to cut it due to its acidity it effects our eyes makes us weeping.

Answer (score -1):

> [image]
>  It's an Ogre because Ogres are like onions and will probably make you weep if you cut them.

Comment: how are Ogre's used in our daily life?